# Can Bazel be instructed to use a single command for updating N targets?

Tags: bazel

The Google Bazel build tool makes it easy enough to explain that each CoffeeScript file in a particular directory tree needs to be compiled to a corresponding output JavaScript file:

```
[genrule(
    name = 'compile-' + f,
    srcs = [f],
    outs = [f.replace('src/', 'static/').replace('.coffee', '.js')],
    cmd = 'coffee --compile --map --output $$(dirname $@) $<',
) for f in glob(['src/**/*.coffee'])]
```

But given, say, 100 CoffeeScript files, this will invoke the `coffee` tool 100 separate times, adding many seconds to the compilation process. If instead it could be explained to Bazel that the `coffee` command can take many input files as input, then files could be batched together and offered to fewer `coffee` invocations, allowing the startup time of the process to be amortized over more files than just one.

Is there any way to explain to Bazel that `coffee` can be invoked with many files at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked with coffee script, so this may need to be adjusted (particularly the `--output @D` part), but something like this might work:

```
coffee_files = glob(['src/**/*.coffee'])

genrule(
    name = 'compile-coffee-files',
    srcs = coffee_files,
    outs = [f.replace('src/', 'static/').replace('.coffee', '.js') for f in coffee_files],
    cmd = 'coffee --compile --map --output @D $(SRCS)' % coffee)
```

Note that if just one input coffee script file is changed, the entire genrule will be rerun with all 100 files (the same as with, say, a `java_library` with 100 input java files).

Comment: Thank you — I now realize that I need to ask the question: is there a way to set up Bazel to avoid both problems! I'll go ask that as a separate question.