# Bazel: copy multiple files to binary directory

Tags: bazel

I need to copy some files to binary directory while preserving their names. What I've got so far:

```
filegroup(
    name = "resources",
    srcs = glob(["resources/*.*"]),
)

genrule(
    name = "copy_resources",
    srcs = ["//some/package:resources"],
    outs = [ ],
    cmd = "cp $(SRCS) $(@D)",
    local = 1,
    output_to_bindir = 1,
)
```

Now I have to specify file names in `outs` but I can't seem to figure out how to resolve the labels to obtain the actual file names.

Comment: Related: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bazel-discuss/EoiHjBPLNuY

Comment: You might want to try writing one `genrule` per file, which gives Bazel more information: it would then know that each destination file independently depends on its source file, but not on any other source files — they way you have written it here, Bazel will think that a change in any source file could affect any destination file. You could model it off my rule here, but use `cp` instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169521/

Answer (score 17):

To make a `filegroup` available to a binary (executed using `bazel run`) or to a test (when executed using `bazel test`) then one usually lists the `filegroup` as part of the `data` of the binary, like so:

```py
cc_binary(
    name = "hello-world",
    srcs = ["hello-world.cc"],
    data = [
        "//your_project/other/deeply/nested/resources:other_test_files",
    ],
)
# known to work at least as of bazel version 0.22.0
```

Usually the above is sufficient.

However, the executable must then recurse through the directory structure `"other/deeply/nested/resources/"` in order to find the files from the indicated `filegroup`.

In other words, when populating the `runfiles` of an executable, `bazel` preserves the directory nesting that spans from the `WORKSPACE` root to all the packages enclosing the given `filegroup`.

Sometimes, this preserved directory nesting is undesirable.

---

THE CHALLENGE:

In my case, I had several `filegroup`s located at various points in my project directory tree, and I wanted all the individual files of those groups to end up *side-by-side* in the `runfiles` collection of the test binary that would consume them.

---

My attempts to do this with a `genrule` were unsuccessful.

In order to copy individual files from multiple `filegroup`s, preserving the basename of each file but flattening the output directory, it was necessary to create a **custom rule** in a `bzl` **bazel extension**.

Thankfully, the custom rule is fairly straightforward.

It uses `cp` in a shell command much like the unfinished `genrule` listed in the original question.

The extension file:

```py
# contents of a file you create named: copy_filegroups.bzl
# known to work in bazel version 0.22.0
def _copy_filegroup_impl(ctx):
    all_input_files = [
        f for t in ctx.attr.targeted_filegroups for f in t.files
    ]

    all_outputs = []
    for f in all_input_files:
        out = ctx.actions.declare_file(f.basename)
        all_outputs += [out]
        ctx.actions.run_shell(
            outputs=[out],
            inputs=depset([f]),
            arguments=[f.path, out.path],
            # This is what we're all about here. Just a simple 'cp' command.
            # Copy the input to CWD/f.basename, where CWD is the package where
            # the copy_filegroups_to_this_package rule is invoked.
            # (To be clear, the files aren't copied right to where your BUILD
            # file sits in source control. They are copied to the 'shadow tree'
            # parallel location under `bazel info bazel-bin`)
            command="cp $1 $2")

    # Small sanity check
    if len(all_input_files) != len(all_outputs):
        fail("Output count should be 1-to-1 with input count.")

    return [
        DefaultInfo(
            files=depset(all_outputs),
            runfiles=ctx.runfiles(files=all_outputs))
    ]


copy_filegroups_to_this_package = rule(
    implementation=_copy_filegroup_impl,
    attrs={
        "targeted_filegroups": attr.label_list(),
    },
)
```

Using it:

```py
# inside the BUILD file of your exe
load(
    "//your_project:copy_filegroups.bzl",
    "copy_filegroups_to_this_package",
)

copy_filegroups_to_this_package(
    name = "other_files_unnested",
    # you can list more than one filegroup:
    targeted_filegroups = ["//your_project/other/deeply/nested/library:other_test_files"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "hello-world",
    srcs = ["hello-world.cc"],
    data = [
        ":other_files_unnested",
    ],
)
```

You can clone a [complete working example here](https://github.com/pestophagous/examples/commit/02f50881e510b778d939679a65eefba57b5bc2b9).

Comment: This doesn't work as of Bazel 2.0, depset is no longer iterable.

Comment: @DavidSauter Adding `to_list()` works for the line `f for t in ctx.attr.targeted_filegroups for f in t.files.to_list()`. This is from https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.18.1/skylark/backward-compatibility.html#depset-is-no-longer-iterable