# How to use --save_temps in Bazel rule instead of command line?

Tags: bazel

Is there a way to control the Bazel build to generate wanted temp files for a list of source files instead of just using the command line option "--save_temps"?

One way is using a cc_binary, and add "-E" option in the "copts", but the obj file name will always have a ".o". This kind of ".o" files will be overwriten by the other build targets. I don't know how to control the compiler output file name in Bazel.

Any better ideas?

Comment: As for .o files you can get them by unpacking the .a file ("a" stands for archive) using a genrule.

Answer (score 0):

cc_library has an [output group](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/rules.html#requesting-output-files) with the static library, which you can then extract. Something like this:

```py
filegroup(
    name = "extract_archive",
    srcs = [":some_cc_library"],
    output_group = "archive",
)
```

Many tools will accept the static archive instead of an object file. If the tool you're using does, then that's easy. If not, things get a bit more complicated.

Extracting the object file from the static archive is a bit trickier. You could use a [genrule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/general.html#genrule) with the `$(AR)` [Make variable](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/make-variables.html#custom_variables), but that won't work with some C++ toolchains that require additional flags to configure architectures etc.

The better (but more complicated) answer is to follow the guidance in [integrating with C++ rules](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/integrating-with-rules-cc.html). You can get the `ar` from the toolchain and the flags to use it in a [custom rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/rules.html), and then create an action to extract it. You could also access the [OutputGroupInfo](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/lib/OutputGroupInfo.html) from the `cc_library` in the rule directly instead of using `filegroup` if you've already got a custom rule.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your suggestions.

Now I think I can solve this problem in two steps(Seems Bazel does not allow to combine two rules into one):
Step1, add a -E option like a normal cc_libary, we can call it a pp_library. It is easy.

Step2, in a new rules, its input is the target of pp_library, then in this rule find out the obj files(can be found via : action.outputs.to_list()) and copy them to the a new place via ctx.actions.run_shell() [run_shell.](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/lib/actions.html#run_shell)

I take [Bazel: copy multiple files to binary directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905256/bazel-copy-multiple-files-to-binary-directory) as a reference.