# How to materialize Bazel Outputs

Tags: python, bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-python

I am relatively new to bazel, so this is probably a relatively simple question.

I have a bunch of libraries defined in my build structure. Something like this:

```
/libraries
- /lib1
  - BUILD
  - files.py
- /lib2
  - BUILD
  - sub_dir
    - other_file.py
    - __init__.py
  - file.json
  - other_file.py
```

The targets look like this:

```
load("@rules_python//python:defs.bzl", "py_library")

py_library(
    name = "lib2",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.py"]),
    data = ["file.json"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [requirement("pandas")],
)
```

Now, when I run build: `bazel build //lib2` the command completes, but no output are actually generated in `bazel-bin` or `bazel-out`.

From what I understand that is due to the fact that `py_library` acts as provider, so the results are not materialized?

Use case is that I have a cloud service where I want to deploy these files to. So I would need to generate an output folder that is deployable (zip would work as well, but ideal)

I already tried the following solutions:

1. use `pkg_zip` rule, however this seems broken, as it does not include sub-dirs and no dependencies
2. `filegroup` target, but that also does not generate any output

I also have a bunch of unit tests so I can verify that the code generation is actually correct and working.
This has been a nail-biter, as I haven't found much good documentation on Bazel so far, so any help would be appreciated!!

---

**Update:** Thanks for the answers below (cannot accept them due to too little points). I originally wanted to use this for azure functions deployment, so I indeed ended up using a py_binary and leveraged and additional copy_macro (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905256/bazel-copy-multiple-files-to-binary-directory)) that I had to modify a bit to make sure all files are in the same folder for seemless deployment. A bit more tedious than I would have hoped, but it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Python rules, as with most other Bazel rule ecosystems, you need a `py_binary` or `py_test` or similar to do much of anything. `py_library` is only useful as a dependency of other Python rules.

All rules return [providers](https://bazel.build/extending/rules#providers) (including `py_library`, `py_binary`, and `py_test`). A simplified version of what `bazel build :x` does is:

1. Look at the [DefaultInfo.files](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/DefaultInfo#files) provider field for `:x`
2. Build those files
3. Print the paths to them (subject to [--show_result](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--show_result))

`py_library`'s `DefaultInfo.files` is empty, so `bazel build lib2` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Bazel has three main types of targets: libraries, binaries, and tests.

- Library: code that's used by other targets
- Binary: creates an executable that can de deployed
- Test: tests either a library or a binary (usually libraries)

So you're looking for the `py_binary` rule.

https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/main/docs/python.md#py_binary

https://bazel.build/reference/be/python#py_binary